# Beginner in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am a beginner in Sharepoint  and I have experience of working with .Net frame work .The  problem is  how to use Visual Studio 2010 and Sql server  in Sharepoint.

Whether it have a web config file where we write the Sql Connection like that or we have to use other things in Sharepoint.
How to use the Stored procedures in sharepoint.
How to use the Authentication and Authorization  process in the sharepoint.
Whether there is any way of usage of MVC  architecture in the sharepoint
Well Thank in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

All your questions will be answered if you learn Sharepoint However, yes you can develop for Sharepoint in visual studio, connecting it with SQL Server (Sharepoint needs a database) and you can use Stored Procedures.

I strongly suggest that you search for some resources to help you get started with Sharepoint Development and/or administration to get the full idea; here are some resources (to name a few) to help you get started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint

http://sharepointmagazine.net/

http://www.sharepointsaturday.org/default.aspx

http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/

http://www.microsoft.com/atwork/default.aspx